# Android Custom IME use default on screen keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime, on-screen-keyboard

When creating an IME for Android you need to support the on screen keyboard (OSK) via overriding many of the InputMethodService methods such as onCreateInputView().

Is there a way to use the on screen keyboard from the users default IME.  For example lets say the Android default IME is their default IME.  When using my IME is there a way to use the OSK from the Android default IME instead of having to manually handle the entire thing (including prediction, etc).  I do not want to replace the users on screen keyboard with this IME.

Alternatively I could probably pull in the source for the android default keyboard and use that.

Comment: I believe your idea to pull it in from Android open source code is the best solution.

Comment: I've been working on that.  The Android LatinIME source seems to be quite dependent on being compiled from within AOSP.

Answer (score 0):

there is absolutely no way you can achieve this. Think the default IME as a separate App & you can't control that from another app. My suggestion would be to pull the LatinIME source code from AOSP & then use it to create your own IME. And trust me almost 99% (just to be safe, but I think it's 100%) of the keyboards in the PlayStore used LatinIME as their starting point. There're a lot of things to handle in a keyboard.